# gensim LdaMulticore is not running from Command Prompt

Tags: python, nlp, multicore, gensim, lda

I am using gensim LdaMulticore to extract topics.It works perfectly fine from Jupyter/Ipython notebook, but when I run from Command prompt, the loop runs indefinitely.
Once the execution arrives at the LdaMulticore function, the execution starts from first. 
Please help me as I am novice

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    model = models.LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus_train, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=20, chunksize=4000, passes=30, alpha=0.5, eta=0.05, decay=0.5, eval_every=10, workers=3, minimum_probability=0)

**RESULTS:-**
Moving to Topics Extraction Script---------------------------------
2017-08-18 18:59:36,448 : INFO : using serial LDA version on this node
2017-08-18 18:59:37,183 : INFO : running online LDA training, 20 topics, 1 passes over the supplied corpus of 400 documents, updating every 12000 documents, evaluating every ~400 documents, iterating 50x with a convergence threshold of 0.001000    
2017-08-18 18:59:37,183 : WARNING : too few updates, training might not converge; consider increasing the number of passes or iterations to improve accuracy
2017-08-18 18:59:37,183 : INFO : training LDA model using 3 processes
2017-08-18 18:59:37,214 : INFO : PROGRESS: pass 0, dispatched chunk #0 = documents up to #400/400, outstanding queue size 1
Importing required Packages
```

Importing required Packages [image]

Comment: I just came to say that I have the same problem but in reverse. I can run Ldamulticore on the terminal, but if I do it on a Jupyter notebook, the loops run infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

LdaMulticore uses all CPU cores to parallelize and speed up processing.
Parallelization uses multiprocessing concept; So you will have to write your program so that it supports mulitprocessing concept.

I had the same issue ,so I replaced LdaMulticore with LdaModel and it worked fine.

```
`gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=4, id2word=dictionary)`
```